# How do I assign the same class value to two or more variables in Python, so they are not under the same ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im attempting to implement entities inside of a text based game, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue.

```
class entity:
    name = "0"
    health = 100
    strenght = 10
    speed = 10
    xp = 0
    energy = 100 

player = entity
player.name = input("Enter your name: ").strip()
print(f"Welcome, {player.name}.")

enemy = entity
enemy.name = "Some Enemy"
enemy.strenght = 5
enemy.speed = 20
enemy.xp = 100
```

So what im trying to achieve here is to have both the enemy and the player be defined as "entity" but to be under different ID's.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean to create an instance of `entitiy` for your varabels? `player = entity()` & `enemy = entity()`?

Comment: That works perfectly well, im new at this so these kinds of things fly right over my head most of the time, thank you for your swift response!

Answer (score 0):

use create object from class instead of change parameters